# An error occurred after signing in to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

The problem is about logging in. It will exit automatically after a few seconds. This problem does not apply to other Windows users. For some reason, it is not possible to reinstall it. Can anyone help?
After resetting the Chrome settings and disabling the antivirus and firewall, it didn't work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> This problem does not apply to other Windows users.

This means you have a damaged Windows User Profile.

If you wish to use the same User Profile (Microsoft Account for instance), you can back up everything in profile, delete it and replace it (using an Admin User to do this).

Often, it is just a simple and almost as fast to reinstall Windows.